# margin of error X, differentials

Tags: calculus

I've got this problem:

> The stem of a particular mushroom has a cylindrical shape. A stem with $2$ cm of height and $r$ centimeters of radius which has a volume $V=2 \pi r^2$. Use differentials to determine the approximated increase of the stem's volume where its radius grows from $0.4$cm to $0.5$cm.

So I got the $dr$ from the difference of $0.4 - 0.5$ which means its result was $0.1$. Right after that, $Dv=4 \pi r dr$. I calculated this without the value of $r$ and I think you can't do it that way, the result was $1.256r \ \text{cm}^3$ but I think there is something left.

Comment: When you write "phi", do you mean "pi" ($\pi$)? Phi is the name of a different letter, which looks like $\phi$ or $\varphi$.

Comment: It is not a *differential equation*, you were probably asked to use *differentials*.  You could use your calculator to find, in this case, the *exact* change in volume. Your answer is much larger than the actual change, which is kind of an indication your answer may be wrong. The procedure, as far as I can guess from what is written, is right. You got $4\pi r\,dr$. Ask yourself now, what is the appropriate $r$? What is the appropriate $dr$?

Comment: I edited the differential equation to differentials, sorry, my bad but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I do not have the value of  $r$ . should I clear $r$ ? or should I simply express it that way?

Comment: You *do* have the value of $r$. Rather, you have *two* values of $r$, as you are told the radius grows from .4 to .5. The starting value of $r$ is the one you want to use when talking about the "augment" (or, increase) in volume.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me

Comment: $dr$ is $0.5-0.4$ (it's `final value-initial value`), not $0.4-0.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the volume is $V=2\pi r^2$, if $r$ increases to $r+dr$ you have the new volume $V'=2\pi (r + dr)^2$.  You are asked for the increase in volume, which is $Dv=2\pi (r + dr)^2 - 2\pi r^2$.  (I am using your notation-I would suggest if the volume is $V$, the change in volume should be $DV$ or $dV$).  The method of differentials says that $(dr)^2$ is negligible compared with $dr$, so you are correct in finding $Dv=4 \pi r\  dr$.  Although $r$ varies in the problem, we have agreed to ignore the variation except where it is indicated specifically, so it would be consistent to use anything in the range $0.4 - 0.5$.  If you care about the difference in the answers you get, you need to use a more accurate method.